# Codeigniter urlencode exclamation mark in a link not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode

OK so if I urlencode a string that contains spaces, exclamation marks, single quotes etc, and echo it in the page I see that the string including the exclamation mark has been encoded as one would expect. However, if I put the encoded string in an `<a href=` the exclamation mark and single quotes are no longer encoded, and CI throws an error about disallowed characters in the url.

```
<?
$string = 'Hello\'s world!';
$url = urlencode(stringtolower($string));

// echo it
echo $url; // outputs: hello%27s+world%21
?>

<a href="<? echo base_url() . $url; ?>">Link</>' <!-- outputs: ./hello's+world! -->
```

What the devil is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not output anything different, really, as you can see when you run your code as is (with removed base_url()-call) on the commandline; then you get:

```
hello%27s+world%21
<a href="hello%27s+world%21">link</a>
```

I assume you are looking at the link in your browser which show's you the second variant in the status bar.

A quick test shows that on a Mac Chrome and Safari don't do this, but Firefox does which I assume you're using. So no need to worry. If you enter the hello%27s+world%21 variant directly in the address field, it also gets automatically switched to the more readable variant.

As for the CI error. Not all characters are allowed to be passed through the internal URI handling, you can either adapt the `permitted_uri_chars` setting in the config file, or pass the argument as GET variable, if you do need any such characters in the url.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| ....
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.,:_\-';
```

Comment: That's a top answer. Yes I only tried it in firefox and because I was getting the error from CI I didn't try in other browsers. The CI error has now gone since I have put a function in the controller to receive the link. However that through me because I would have expected the 404 instead of the invalid character error. Thanks for seeing straight through my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stripslashes()` :

```
$string = stripslashes( 'Hello\'s world!' );
$url = urlencode(stringtolower($string));
```